# AWS adding custom load balancer rule for a single rest endpoint

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

Is there a way to configure a specific rule for AWS load balancer to one rest endpoint? We are developing a new version of our project, it implies changes for one endpoint rest, so we would like to put into production environment and only test this single endpoint.
It means, all request should be redirected to old project except for the single endpoint. The request to the single endpoint should be balanced between the newer and older endpoint.
Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, but I don't understand what's problem. Can you give details on `redirected to old project except for the single endpoint.` and `balanced between the newer and older endpoint`

Comment: having for example three endpoints called: "/a" "/b" and "/c", we are developing a new version of "/a", and we would like to test how works this new version into production. So we were thinking about if we can start a new ec2 using our new endpoint "/a", but only for a few percentage of request. B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may understand your problem now.

I will recommend to set a similar environment as QA or development environment, so with that you can test the changes before deploy to production.

But if you don't have, or want to save cost, here is the work around.

For example, you have load balancer `ELB-A` and ec2 `instance-A`,`instance-B` and `Instance-C`

If you need test the code on instance-A only, set another `ELB-B`, connect to instance-A, and disable instance-A on ELB-A. [Deregister and Register Amazon EC2 Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_DeReg_Reg_Instances.html)

After waiting for several minutes, no traffic to Instance-A, and you can take snapshot and make change on instance-A, and test from ELB-B. If it is fine, register that instance to ELB-A.